# How to execute a function for each period of time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

I want a certain function to run every round hour. There is the solution of running an interval when it's a round hour but I often turn on and off my script and I don't want to have to run it exactly on a round hour.
I've tried looking through some npm modules and I found one but I had some issues with it. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: You should look into setting up a scheduler and running it at AWS. The integration for doing this in node is very good there.

Comment: If you don't want to use AWS, you can use any linux machine with cron installed and set to run your node script hourly https://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60;

   function hourly() {
      //....

      setTimeout(hourly, HOUR);
  }

  setTimeout(hourly, HOUR - (new Date % HOUR));
```

Just calculate the next full hour when the server starts, and then shedule an hourly timer.

*I admit that it might loose accuracy due to leap seconds :)*

Comment: I'll try that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No need for javascript! You have the perfect tool for that if you use linux!
Use cron:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

This will open a vim editor. Then add:

```
0 * * * * node /execute/your/script.js
```

(basically, it will run your code every hour on its minute zero)

**More info**
cron: https://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/